# Compilation error in Lombok's Annotation - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, annotations, lombok

I am using Eclipse 2020-06. I installed lombok via installer from the official website.
There is a compilation error in my class, even with the correct imports.

[project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoEzo.png)

What could be wrong with my project?

Answer (score 0):

I think lombok maven dependency is missing in your POM file, add it n check:---

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.10</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```